# Is there a way to use a custom OrderBy or Min without having to implement an IComparer<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

What I'm trying to write is

```
        return possibilities.OrderBy((x, y) =>
            {
                // returns true or false depending on whether x is 
                // lexographically smaller than y, e.g. x={1,2,3} 
                // is lexographically smaller than y={1,3,2}
                for(int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if(x[i] < y[i])
                        return true;
                    else if(x[i] > y[i])
                        return false;
                }
                return true;
            })
            .First();
```

where `possibilities` is of type `IEnumerable<int[]>`. However, I was surprised that this syntax is not valid and that everything I can find by Googling indicates that I would have to write a bunch of extra code to implement an `IComparer<int[]>`. Really?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Comparer<T>.Create(Comparison<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198) can be used in .NET 4.5 or later:

```
IEnumerable<int[]> a = new[] { new []{ 1, 2 }, new[] { 3, 4 } };

int[] min = a.OrderBy(x => x, Comparer<int[]>.Create((x, y) => {
    for (int z, i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
        if ((z = x[i] - y[i]) != 0) return z;
    return 0;
})).FirstOrDefault();
```

But that's not needed to find the minimum:

```
int[] min = a.Aggregate((x, y) => {
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i) {
        if (x[i] < y[i]) return x;
        if (x[i] > y[i]) return y;
    }
    return x;
});
```

Comment: @JonHanna how OrderBy().FirstOrDefault()  can be O(1)? Maybe O(n)?

Comment: @Evk darn it. That's the second time I've written O(1) when I meant O(n) this week, and it's too late to edit, but too misleading to leave, so I'd better re-comment.

Comment: `OrderBy(…).FirstOrDefault()` is O(n) in .NET Core, so that objection only applies to some framework versions.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement and reuse comparer which accepts compare delegate, like this:

```
public class DynamicComparer<T> : IComparer<T> {
    private readonly Func<T, T, int> _comparer;
    public DynamicComparer(Func<T, T, int> comparer) {
        _comparer = comparer;
    }
    public int Compare(T x, T y) {
        return _comparer(x, y);
    }
}
```

And then use it in all places you need:

```
possibilities.OrderBy(c => c, new DynamicComparer<int[]>((x, y) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (x[i] < y[i])
            return -1;
        else if (x[i] > y[i])
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}));
```

Note that as another answer suggests, there is already such comparer in .NET 4.5, which can be created with `Comparer<int[]>.Create`. If you are on .NET 4.5 - no need to create your own comparer like that.

You can even go futher and implement your own OrderBy extension method:

```
public static class Extensions {
    public static IOrderedEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, T, int> comparer) {
        return items.OrderBy(c => c, new DynamicComparer<T>(comparer));
    }
}
```

Then it becomes just like you want:

```
possibilities.OrderBy((x, y) =>
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; ++i)
    {
      if (x[i] < y[i])
          return -1;
      else if (x[i] > y[i])
          return 1;
      }
      return 0;
 });
```

Answer (score -2):

I think an easy way to do it would be

```
return possibilities.OrderBy(x => String.Join(".",x.ToString.PadLeft(10,'0'))).First();
```

the reason for the . is to separate the segments, the reason for the pad left to length of 10 with 0s is that the max int is 2 billion, so 10 maximum characters.

Comment: Given {1,1,12} and {1,11,2}, the generated strings would be identical, but they should not compare as equal.

Comment: That change looks like it covers most potential problems if you additionally switch to `StringComparer.Ordinal`, but one thing that is not obvious is how it handles negative numbers. I *think* that you may have got that working, but if so, it could definitely use a comment in your answer.

Comment: hmm the minus sign comes in as a lower ascii than the numbers, but -2 is lower than -1 so it wouldn't work correctly for that. I think next time i'm going to try and do an answer like this i'll actually do it in visual studio and check it first.

Comment: Oh of course, I feel silly for having missed that myself. Also, the minus sign adds one to the maximum length.